# A riddling rhyme: Far

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, language

> You are far away yet you are near,
>
> You are far away yet I can hear,
>
> You were rather close now you are not,
>
> You sent me a message of that I got,
>
> You are far away yet I can see,
>
> You're looking for a word can you name me?

---

**Update**
After showing this my colleagues, some of them think I've gone about this a little wrong. Therefore I'll give a little hint for those that want it. I hope I haven't spoiled it.

> Technically it's not a word, but a prefix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it the prefix:

> tele-

You are far away yet you are near,

> telescope

You are far away yet I can hear,

> telephone

You were rather close now you are not,

> teleport?

You sent me a message of that I got,

> telegraph

You are far away yet I can see,

> television

Comment: I have to admit the hint really helped.

Comment: Welp, you beat me to it by 2 minutes :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yeah I saw yours right after I posted. :p

Comment: Excellent, you named all the tele- words I was thinking of.

Comment: Great. So proud. This is one of the few sites that require almost no specialized knowledge. :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> memory?

I think so because:

You are far away yet you are near,

> memories remind of people who we feel close to

You are far away yet I can hear,

> one tends to remember the words as they were spoken

You were rather close now you are not,

> one often remembers those who are not in touch

You sent me a message of that I got,

> memories are associative of events and messages

You are far away yet I can see,

> one can visualize the speakers from memories

You're looking for a word can you name me?

> self explanatory

Comment: I like this answer, it does fit, but it's not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Given the new hint, my guess is

> TELE

because it's a

> Greek-derived prefix meaning "far away".

*You are far away yet you are near,*

> "Tele" means far away, but many tele-things are actually quite near us all the time.

*You are far away yet I can hear,*

> Tele-phone means roughly "far away hearing".

*You were rather close now you are not,*
*You sent me a message of that I got,*

> Tele-things can often me used to send messages - especially telephones as referenced in the previous line.

*You are far away yet I can see,*

> Tele-vision means roughly "far away seeing".

*You're looking for a word can you name me?*

> Not a word but a prefix (unless you count the homophone "telly").

Comment: Very good, you're the only person to have mentioned the Greek meaning given in the title. I need to give Holly the accept as she got all the tele- words I was thinking of. In your opinion, as I'm new and you've been a member for years; to help me in puzzle building in the future, should I have given the hint?

Comment: @Jack No worries, Holly definitely deserves the accept. Re the hint - in my opinion, it was a bit too much of a giveaway, because "prefix" and "far away" would *immediately* put the correct answer into a lot of people's heads. A more cryptic hint, maybe something like "I am a word but not a word", would have made it a bit more challenging.

Answer (score 1):

is it a

> satellite?

because

> satellites orbiting the earth are far away, but still not THAT far away from the earth 
>  satellites are used for telecommunications, so they can "hear" 
>  because they're orbiting the earth, the distance between us and them vary 
>  they're used for telecommunications so they recieve messages 
>  some are used to take pictures of the earth, so they can see

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Phone

You are far away yet you are near,

> Phones allow us bring others close who are far away (skype, facetime, call, text, etc)

You are far away yet I can hear,

> this could be a phone call

You were rather close now you are not,

> perhaps you ended the call? or the person traveled away and was originally there

You sent me a message of that I got,

> this could be a text or sms message

You are far away yet I can see,

> going back to the factime/skype video chat

Comment: Closest answer yet...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it is a

> (Moving) STAR

As,

> A star is far away and it rhymes with far.
>  It sends signals( electromagnetic radiation/radio signals)
>  Stars are usually supposed to be moving away from *us* ( As per some theories of astronomy) and hence it is close/near now but not a moment later!
>  You can see a star, though it is far off!

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer. Is it

> Video? 
>  I was initially thinking of a video call, but realised that video also suffices for the mentioned puzzle.

I think so because:

You are far away yet you are near,

> Videos help you see folks at a distance on a screen

You are far away yet I can hear,

> Self explanatory from previous question

You were rather close now you are not,

> People appear close on the screen but are not actually

You sent me a message of that I got,

> Videos deliver messages

You are far away yet I can see,

> Videos can be shot anywhere at faroff location

You're looking for a word can you name me?

> self explanatory